# How to prove asymptotic solution for recurrence equation: $T(n) = 2T(n/4)+4T(n/8) + n$ for $n>8$ with $T(n) = 1$ for $1 \leq n \leq 8$?

Tags: recurrence-relations

As title says, how does one solve $T(n) = 2T(n/4)+4T(n/8)+n$ for $n>8$ with $T(n)=1$ when $1 \leq n \leq 8$?

Comment: Have you tried a few examples, say for $8<n\leq 16$?

Comment: Is $n$ a natural number here? If so, then you can only test the recurrence relation for multiples of $8$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we start by solving the following recurrence:
$$T(n) = 2T(\lfloor n/4 \rfloor) + 4T(\lfloor n/8 \rfloor) + n$$
where $T(1) = 1$ and $T(0) = 0.$

We will adapt this solution to the case where $T(n) = 1$
when $1\le n\le 8.$

Now let $$n = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} d_k 2^k$$
be the binary representation of $n.$

We unroll the recursion to obtain an **exact** formula for $n\ge 1$
$$T(n) =  [z^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}] \frac{1}{1-2z^2-4z^3}
+ \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor-1} 
[z^j] \frac{1}{1-2z^2-4z^3} 
\sum_{k=j}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} d_k 2^{k-j}.$$

Now the roots of $1-2z^2-4z^3$ are
$$\rho_0 = \frac{1}{2}, 
\quad\rho_{1,2} = -\frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{1}{2}i$$

Applying partial fractions by residues we obtain
$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=\rho_0}
\frac{1}{1-2z^2-4z^3} 
= \frac{1}{-4\rho_0-12\rho_0^2}
= -\frac{1}{5}$$

and
$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=\rho_{1,2}}
\frac{1}{1-2z^2-4z^3} 
= \frac{1}{5} \left(\frac{1}{2}\mp i\right)$$

Using $$[z^j] \frac{1}{z-\rho} = 
- [z^j] \frac{1}{\rho} \frac{1}{1-z/\rho}
= -\frac{1}{\rho^{j+1}}$$
this yields

$$[z^j] \frac{1}{1-2z^2-4z^3} =
\frac{1}{5} 2^{j+1}
- \frac{1}{5} \left(\frac{1}{2} - i\right) \rho_1^{-j-1}
- \frac{1}{5} \left(\frac{1}{2} + i\right) \rho_2^{-j-1}$$

which becomes
$$\frac{1}{5} 2^{j+1}
-\frac{1}{5} \left(-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}i\right)
\sqrt{2}^j \exp(-3/4\pi i j)
-\frac{1}{5} \left(-\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2}i\right)
\sqrt{2}^j \exp(+3/4\pi i j)$$

which finally yields
$$\frac{1}{5} 2^{j+1}
+ \frac{3}{5} \sqrt{2}^j \cos(3/4 \pi j)
- \frac{1}{5} \sqrt{2}^j \sin(3/4 \pi j).$$

This admits some additional simplification as in
$$\frac{1}{5} 2^{j+1}
+ \frac{\sqrt{10}}{5} \frac{3}{\sqrt{10}} \sqrt{2}^j \cos(3/4 \pi j)
- \frac{\sqrt{10}}{5} \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} \sqrt{2}^j \sin(3/4 \pi j).$$

Putting $\beta = \arctan(3, -1) \approx -0.3217505544$ where the first
argument of  the arctangent  is the $y$  coordinate as  implemented in
Maple or the C math library we get
$$c_j = \frac{1}{5} 2^{j+1}
+ \frac{\sqrt{10}}{5} \sqrt{2}^j 
\sin(3/4 \pi j + \beta).$$

We now compute lower and  upper bounds which are actually attained and
cannot  be improved upon.  For the  lower bound  consider a  one digit
followed by a string of zeroes, to give

$$T(n) \ge c_{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor}
+ \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor-1} 
c_j 2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor-j}
\\ = c_{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor}
+ 2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor-1} 
c_j  2^{-j}
\\ = c_{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor}
+ \frac{2}{5} \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor 2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} 
+ 2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} 
\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor-1}
\frac{\sqrt{10}}{5} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}^j}
\sin(3/4 \pi j + \beta).$$

The sum term can be shown to converge to a number (albeit very slowly)
namely $8/25$ and we get the lower bound asymptotic

$$c_{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor}
+ \frac{2}{5} \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor 2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} 
+ \frac{8}{25}2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}.$$

We see that the middle term dominates.

For an upper bound consider a string of one digits to get
$$T(n) \le  c_{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} +
\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor-1} 
c_j \sum_{k=j}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} 2^{k-j}
\\ = c_{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} +
\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor-1} 
c_j (2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor -j +1} -1).$$

The  same constant  appears as  in the  lower bound,  multiplied  by a
factor  of  two.

We get as a first asymptotic
$$c_{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor}
+ \frac{4}{5} \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor 2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} 
+ \frac{16}{25}2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}.$$

The error term being subtracted is
$$\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor-1}  c_j$$
with dominant asymptotics
$$\frac{2}{5} \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor-1}  2^j
\sim \frac{2}{5} 2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}$$

for a final upper bound asymptotic
$$c_{\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor}
+ \frac{4}{5} \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor 2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} 
+ \frac{6}{25}2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}.$$

Joining the  upper and the lower  bound we get for  the asymptotics of
the recurrence that it is

$$T(n)\in\Theta\left(\lfloor \log_2  n \rfloor
\times 2^{\lfloor \log_2  n \rfloor}\right)
= \Theta\left(\lfloor \log_2  n \rfloor 2^{\ \log_2  n}\right) 
= \Theta(n \times \log n),$$
which, let it be said, could also have been obtained by inspection.

**Remark.** We can merge the first term from the exact formula into
the sum  but this does not affect  the proceedings and is  left at the
reader's discretion. This is

$$\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} 
[z^j] \frac{1}{1-2z^2-4z^3} 
\sum_{k=j}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} d_k 2^{k-j}.$$

To  complete this computation  we now  take into  account that  the OP
asked for a solution where $T(n) = 1$ for $1\le n\le 8.$
Call this $S_2(n).$

First solve for $S_1(n)$ where $S_1(n) = 1$ for $1\le n\le 15.$

We obtain the exact formula for $n\ge 16$
$$\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor -4} 
[z^j] \frac{1}{1-2z^2-4z^3} 
\sum_{k=j}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} d_k 2^{k-j}
+ \sum_{j=\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor -3}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor -2} 
[z^j] \frac{1}{1-2z^2-4z^3}
\\ + [z^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor -1}] \frac{4z^3}{1-2z^2-4z^3}.$$

Finally we need to correct for the interval $8\lt n\le 15$ where $S_1$
assigns the value one instead of $T(n).$ Introduce
$$ q = \lfloor n/2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor-3} \rfloor.$$

This  completes the  formula,  adding the  correction factor  (Iverson
bracket) 
$$[[q\gt 8]] \times (q+5) \times
[z^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor -3}] \frac{1}{1-2z^2-4z^3}.$$

It then follows by inspection that the asymptotics of $S_2(n)$
are the same as those of $T(n).$

**Addendum.** The evaluation of the constant follows from
$$\left. \frac{1}{1-2z^2-4z^3} 
+ \frac{1}{5}\frac{1}{z-1/2}\right|_{z=1/2}
= \left. 1/5\,{\frac {2\,z+3}{2\,{z}^{2}+2\,z+1}} \right|_{z=1/2}
= \frac{8}{25}.$$